# how to display my location(blue dot) in google maps using simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

I am not getting my current location (blue dot) in simulator mode.I read that we need to set
mylocation property to "yes" but I did not got any dot on the map.Also I want to update the map as I change my location and for which I had used "addObserver" but I did not got any satisfactory result

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

```
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;

// Listen to the myLocation property of GMSMapView.
[mapView_ addObserver:self
         forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
            options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
            context:NULL];

 self.view = mapView_;
```

Answer (score 1):

when you have simulator open, go to menu DEBUG (this is language dependent, so adjust according to your language) / location. Select Custom location, enter your lat / lon.

Comment: @Armand.I had already done it but still i am not getting required results

Comment: then your system is broken

Comment: Did you set `self.map.showsUserLocation = YES;`or by code or in StoryBoard ?